# Basic question on almost complex structures and Chern classes of homogeneous spaces

Tags: algebraic-topology, characteristic-classes, homogeneous-spaces

Toward the end of "Characteristic Classes and Homogeneous Spaces, III," Borel and Hirzebruch prove that given a compact Lie group $G$ and toral subgroup $T$ (no restriction on rank), one has $w(G/T) = 1$ and $p(G/T) = 1$: the Stiefel–Whitney and Pontrjagin classes are trivial. In fact they show the tangent bundle of $G/T$ is stably trivial.

They say a similar statement is valid for Chern classes in the almost complex case. I guess that means that whenever $G/T$ is almost complex, $c(G/T) = 1$. **Is that right?** I suppose it's clear that if the underlying real bundle of a complex vector bundle is stably trivial, then the complex vector bundle is also stably trivial; just add a higher (even) number of trivial real line bundles.

I don't know anything about almost-complexity. I do know that $U(n)/U(1)^n$ is a complete flag manifold $Fl(\mathbb{C}^n)$, and from induction on fiberings $Fl(\mathbb{C}^{n-1}) \to Fl(\mathbb{C}^n) \to \mathbb{C}P^n$, that its Euler characteristic is $n!$, meaning its top Chern class is nonzero if it is defined. So, working backwards, I guess $Fl(\mathbb{C}^n)$ isn't almost complex, though I would have thought it should be. I don't know what happens to the other Chern classes even in this case.

I do know that if $T$ is *not* a maximal torus, then the Euler characteristic of $G/T$ is zero. But in this case, too, I don't know anything about Chern classes. Or maybe there's nothing to know. **Suppose $G$ is a compact Lie group and $T$ is a nonmaximal torus. Can $G/T$ admit an almost complex structure?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They aren't actually referring to an almost complex structure, but to a real-stable version of it.

On the top of pg. 494:  A bundle $\xi$ is called complex if $\xi \oplus 1^n$ (where $1^n$ is the $n$-dim trivial real bundle) has a complex structure for some $n$.

For example, if $\xi$ is the tangent bundle of $S^2$, then $\xi+1 = 1^3$ is trivial and so $\xi + 1^2 = 1^4$ has a (trivial) complex structure.  It follows that $c(\xi) = 0$.

On the other hand, for the complex manifold $S^2$, $c(TS^2) \neq 0$.

(Note that $S^2 = U(2)/U(1)^2$, so this is directly relevant to your question.)

Finally, to answer your last question, if $G = SU(2) \times T^2$ and $U = S^1\times e\times e$, then $G/U = S^2 \times T^2$ so has a complex structure.  I don't know of any less trivial examples, however.

Comment: First off, (in the middle p. 493, in my copy), they say a real vector bundle has a "weak almost complex structure" if it is stably complex, and then a manifold is "weakly almost complex" if its tangent bundle admits a weak almost complex structure. They just refer to the almost complex case on the later pages, so what the hell, Borel and Hirzebruch? How could you? 

Secondly $S^2 = \mathbb{C}P^1 = Fl(\mathbb{C}^2)$, so I guess invoking other flag manifolds was overkill on my part.

Comment: Thirdly, there is something I'm obviously still not getting. They define the Chern class of a weakly almost complex structure to be that of the almost complex stabilized bundle. They note, using the $S^{2n}$ version of your example, that the Chern class (of appropriate degree) of this stabilized bundle need not be the Euler class of the original bundle. I guess the point is that, if there is a complex structure on the tangent bundle to begin with, this need not be the same as the complex structure on the stabilization.

Comment: What I'm still not getting is this: start with $T(\mathbb{C}P^1)$. We have $T(\mathbb{C}P^1)_{\mathbb{R}} \oplus \underline{\mathbb{C}}_{\mathbb{R}} \cong \underline{\mathbb{R}}^{\oplus 4} = (\underline{\mathbb{C}}^{\oplus 2})_{\mathbb{R}}$, so this has trivial Chern classes. On the other hand, $\mathbb{C}P^1$ does not, which means that $T(\mathbb{C}P^1) \oplus \underline{\mathbb{C}}$ also does not have trivial Chern classes. Is the point that one can't stably trivialize this bundle without realizing and then complexifying again?

Comment: Put another way, is this an artifact of the fact that one real vector bundle can have multiple complex structures? Finally, does this mean that the statement they are making about Chern classes of almost complex structures vanishing is much less interesting than I thought? Because (as you point out) $\mathbb{C}P^1$ is the canonical first example of a compact complex manifold.

Comment: @jdc:  I am far from an expert in this area - but I think you nailed the key issue:  Just because one can choose transition functions in $Gl(2n,\mathbb{R})$ which trivialize a bundle does not mean that they can be chosen in $Gl(n,\mathbb{C})$ and still trivialize the bundle.  I'm not sure if it depends on the fact that real bundle can have multiple complex structures or not, but it does seem likely.  Finally, my understanding is that you are right:  their results on Chern classes of almost complex structures do seem less interesting with this definition.